# Datetime // Assign specific data type in JSON import routine

Tags: python, json, pandas

UPDATE: The import works fine now but I just wonder about the datetime string:

```
"lastUpdateCheck": "2018-09-19T13:26:10.415Z",
```

What does T and Z stand for?

---

I'm using the `pd.read_json()` function to read a simple `.json` file, like listed below. As an alternative, the `json_normalize()` is also in use.

How can I assign the datatypes eg. `datetime64[ns]`, `str`, `int64`, `float64` directly to the pandas dataframe while importing?

```
[
    {
        "deviceId": "0000626_0",
        "brand": "Test",
        "type": "EV_ICCPD",
        "generation": "highG2",
        "currentVersion": "7.8.9",
        "maxAvailableVersion": "7.8.9",
        "name": "0000626_0",
        "lastUpdateCheck": "2018-09-19T13:26:10.415Z",
        "autoUpdate": null
    },
    {
        "deviceId": "0000000167_1",
        "brand": "Test",
        "type": "EV_ICCPD",
        "generation": "highG2",
        "currentVersion": "7.6.2",
        "maxAvailableVersion": "7.8.9",
        "name": "0000000167_1",
        "lastUpdateCheck": "2018-07-31T07:32:13.919Z",
        "autoUpdate": null
    }
]
```

Thank you

Comment: using `dtype` argument https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `dtype` keyword from `pd.read_json()`:

```
my_dtypes = {'lastUpdateCheck': 'datetime64[ns]', 'name': 'str'}

df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(data), dtype=my_dtypes)
```